# Unable to compile T1 Architecture and Simulation modelling tool

Tags: c++, solaris, sparc, sunstudio

First of, I am very new to this. 
I am trying to compile the T1 Architecture and Simulation modelling tool (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/opensparc/opensparc-t1-page-1444609.html), using Sun Studio 12.3 as compiler on Solaris 10 with Sparc processor.

I am running the script "build_sas.sh" and running into compilation error.

```
 --- Building n1 in fw ---
/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC -G -KPIC  -fast -xO5 -DNDEBUG -DRS_INLINE=inline       -DRS_MPSAS_COMPATIBLE    -xarch=v9a -DHOST64BIT=1    -DN1_BOOTS10 -DMEMORY_SPARSE -I../../include/fw -I../../include/mmu -I../../include/strand -I../../include/core -I../../include/cpu -I../../include/asi -I../../include/system -I../../include/trap  -I/scratch/sam-t1/devtools/64/include/python2.4  -c -o obj64opt_n1/Interface/XmlTokenizer.o Interface/XmlTokenizer.cc
CC: Warning: -xarch=v9a is deprecated, use -m64 -xarch=sparcvis instead
"Interface/XmlTokenizer.cc", line 157: Error: Formal argument value of type std::string & in call to Riesling::XmlTokenizer::CallBack::notify(std::string &) requires an lvalue.
"Interface/XmlTokenizer.cc", line 162: Error: Formal argument value of type std::string & in call to Riesling::XmlTokenizer::CallBack::notify(std::string &) requires an lvalue.
"Interface/XmlTokenizer.cc", line 167: Error: Formal argument value of type std::string & in call to Riesling::XmlTokenizer::CallBack::notify(std::string &) requires an lvalue.
3 Error(s) detected.
*** Error code 2
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `obj64opt_n1/Interface/XmlTokenizer.o'
Current working directory /scratch/sam-t1/src/riesling-cm/riesling/src/fw
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `fw'
```

I am not sure what is the error in the source code. Here is the source code:

```
#include "Interface/XmlTokenizer.h"
#include "StdMacros.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Riesling;
XmlTokenizer::XmlTokenizer() :
    startTagHandler_(NULL),
    endTagHandler_(NULL),
    dataHandler_(NULL)
{}

XmlTokenizer::XmlTokenizer( string &xmlString,
        CallBack *start,
        CallBack *end,
        CallBack *data  ) :
    startTagHandler_(start),
    endTagHandler_(end),
    dataHandler_(data)
{
    tokenize( xmlString );
}

XmlTokenizer::XmlTokenizer( const XmlTokenizer & orig ) :
    startTagHandler_(orig.startTagHandler_),
    endTagHandler_(orig.endTagHandler_),
    dataHandler_(orig.dataHandler_)
{}

XmlTokenizer::~XmlTokenizer()
{}

const XmlTokenizer &
XmlTokenizer::operator=( const XmlTokenizer & rhs )
{
    startTagHandler_ = rhs.startTagHandler_;
    endTagHandler_ = rhs.endTagHandler_;
    dataHandler_ = rhs.dataHandler_;
    return *this;
}

bool
XmlTokenizer::operator==( const XmlTokenizer & rhs ) const
{
    return endTagHandler_ == rhs.endTagHandler_ &&
           startTagHandler_ == rhs.startTagHandler_ &&
           dataHandler_ == rhs.dataHandler_;
}

string
XmlTokenizer::toString() const
{
    ostringstream os;
    return os.str();
}

int
XmlTokenizer::nextToken( string::iterator &start,
        string::iterator &end,
        const string::iterator &endOfString )
{
    int result = -1;

    start = end;
    while( start != endOfString && *start != '<' && *start != '>' ){
        ++start;
        if( *start == '\\' && start != endOfString ){
            ++start;
        }
    }

    if( start == endOfString ){
        return END_OF_STRING;
    }

    end = start;
    ++end;

    while( end != endOfString && *end != '<' && *end != '>' ){
        ++end;
        if( *end == '\\' && end != endOfString ){
            ++end;
        }
    }

    if( end == endOfString ){
        return END_OF_STRING;
    }

    if( *start == '<' && *end == '>' ){
        string::iterator i = start;
        while( i != end && *i != '/' ){
            ++i;
        }
        if( i == end ){
            result = START_TAG;
        } else {
            result = END_TAG;
        }
    } else if( *start == '>' && *end == '<' ) {
        ++start;
        result = DATA;
    } else {
        string msg( "Invalid XML \"" );
        msg.append( string( start, end ) ).append( "\"" );
        RIESLING_THROW_DOMAIN_ERROR( msg );
    }

    return result;
}


void
XmlTokenizer::tokenize( string &xmlSt)
{
    int currToken;
    string::iterator start = xmlSt.begin();
    string::iterator end = xmlSt.begin();

    while( (currToken = nextToken(start, end, xmlSt.end())) != END_OF_STRING ) {
        switch( currToken ){
            case START_TAG:
                if( startTagHandler_ ){
                    startTagHandler_->notify( string( start + 1, end ) );
                }
                break;
            case END_TAG:
                if( endTagHandler_ ){
                    endTagHandler_->notify( string( start + 2, end ) );
                }
                break;
            case DATA:
                if( dataHandler_ ){
                    dataHandler_->notify( string( start, end ) );
                }
                break;
            default:
                RIESLING_THROW_DOMAIN_ERROR( "An unknown error occured" );
        }
    }
}

void
XmlTokenizer::setStartTagHandler( CallBack *startTagHandler )
{
    startTagHandler_ = startTagHandler;
}

void
XmlTokenizer::setEndTagHandler( CallBack *endTagHandler )
{
    endTagHandler_ = endTagHandler;
}

void
XmlTokenizer::setDataHandler( CallBack *dataHandler )
{
    dataHandler_ = dataHandler;
}
```

I would really appreciate your help/suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the compiler option `-features=rvalueref`. Are there no build instructions that come with the software?

Answer (score 0):

You forcing SPARC VIS extensions instructions with `-xarch=sparcvis`, which are not included in T1. VIS and VIS+ are UltraSPARC III+ IV+ specific. Run `isainfo -bv` to see what you CPU support. Use `-xarch=native` when you are not crosscompiling.

Comment: "> isainfo -bv :
 64-bit sparcv9 applications:
        vis2 vis" 

So, does it mean it supports sparcvis, or should I go ahead and use the -xarch=native anyways?
Thanks

Comment: If there is `vis2 vis`, then it is not T1... and yes, it supports `sparcvis`. `-xarch=native` make code best for processor, but you can tell exactly what you want. As far as there's `vis2`, you can use `-xarch=sparcvis2` for 32bit binaries or `-xarch=v9b` for 64bit.